# Cannot login as a User even if i am salesforce admin

Tags: user-management, user-admin

A user is currently inactive,i made him as Active ( I have the  salesforce admin profile), after making him active, i cannot see the "Login" button in his user profile.

Any reasons why i cant see the Login button his user profile. I dont want to send an email to the user with his password..

I am trying to login as the user , to know the view he has created for case object.i have to create the same for him in a new org..

Can anyone let me know why i am not seeing the Login button on the user profile..

Answer (score 4):

There is an org-wide setting to allow this under security settings.  See [this description](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000089838&language=en_US)

Comment: As for "why not", it's because without that org-wide setting enabled, users have to explicitly grant access. That means they'd have to login as that user with a password first and explicitly grant access.

Comment: Please include a copy of the linked document in your answer to preserve it in case the link changes